# couldn't send email in asp.net using gmail account

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, gmail

Can we use gmail account to send email in asp.net website from **localhost ** (local machine) ? I am trying but badly unsuccessful. It works fine on hosting but donot work on my machine.

I have windows server 2003 on my machine, I have added port 587 and 465 in firewall in exceptions. In my gmail account I also have enabled POP and IMAP. Some people suggest to use port 465 and others say port 587 should be used. I tried both and below was my result:

1. Using port 465 it take time and finally give message that the opration has timed out. falure
2. Using port 587 it dont take time, show message "failuer sending email" with an inner expection "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 72.14.213.109:587"

Below is my code, please guide me where I am wrong or what I should do.

thanks

```
public static bool SendMail(string gMailAccount, string password, string to, string subject, string message)
{
    try
    {
        NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential(gMailAccount, password);
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress(gMailAccount);
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = message;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = loginInfo;
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Send(msg);

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use smtp.yandex.com. May be need change settings in your gmail account.

Comment: Mikhail what settings I should change in my gmail account ? plz guide

Comment: I don't know. See http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370

Answer (score 0):

Try this firs: add:

```
 client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
```

If that does not help, your mailaddress might not be complete, use

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name");
```

and in the credentials use

```
Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, ....
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This SmtpClient has always worked for me:

```
new SmtpClient
     {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("noreply@my_domain.com", "password")
     };
```

And it matches yours.

Have you been able to contact smtp.gmail.com on port 587 through any other app? Telnet on that port maybe? Am thinking it's probably a network issue, although you did state that your firewall was wide open it's not the only hop between you and google.